# Search and get a line in Python

Tags: python, string, search, line

Is there a way to search, from a string, a line containing another string and retrieve the entire line?

For example:

```py
    string = """
        qwertyuiop
        asdfghjkl
    
        zxcvbnm
        token qwerty

        asdfghjklf
        
    """;
    retrieve_line("token") = "token qwerty"
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

you mentioned "entire line" , so i assumed mystring is the entire line.

```
if "token" in mystring:
    print(mystring)
```

however if you want to just get "token qwerty",

```
>>> mystring="""
...     qwertyuiop
...     asdfghjkl
...
...     zxcvbnm
...     token qwerty
...
...     asdfghjklñ
... """
>>> for item in mystring.split("\n"):
...  if "token" in item:
...     print (item.strip())
...
token qwerty
```

Answer (score 40):

If you prefer a one-liner:

```
matched_lines = [line for line in my_string.split('\n') if "substring" in line]
```

Answer (score 11):

With regular expressions

```
import re
s="""
    qwertyuiop
    asdfghjkl

    zxcvbnm
    token qwerty

    asdfghjklñ
"""
>>> items=re.findall("token.*$",s,re.MULTILINE)
>>> for x in items:
...     print x
...
token qwerty
```

Answer (score 9):

```
items=re.findall("token.*$",s,re.MULTILINE)
>>> for x in items:
```

you can also get the line if there are other characters before token

```
items=re.findall("^.*token.*$",s,re.MULTILINE)
```

The above works like grep token on unix and keyword 'in' or .contains in python and C#

```
s='''
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl

zxcvbnm
token qwerty

asdfghjklñ
'''
```

**http://pythex.org/**
matches the following 2 lines

```
....
....
token qwerty
```