# Print Lines Containing String: Odd Behavior

Tags: loops, for-loop, python-3.x

I am using Python3 to try to emulate

```
awk '/STRING/'
```

I made some code that works, but it stops on the first instance instead of finding all lines that contain the specified character/string.

After I made the code, I saw these two pages, but the suggestions did not work

[Print line containing "word" python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905101/print-line-containing-word-python)

[Search and get a line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557808/search-and-get-a-line-in-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Made by Devyn Collier Johnson, NCLA, Linux+, LPIC-1, DCTS
def cat(openfile): #Emulates cat#
    with open(openfile) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return ''.join(lines)
def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
    for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
        if CONTAINING in item:
            return item.strip()

print(GETLINEWITH(cat('./Base.xaiml'), 'terminal'))
```

I have a file (./Base.xaiml) that contains several instances of the word "terminal".  I am using this file and string for testing purposes.

**EDIT:** I also want to save the results to a variable -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Made by Devyn Collier Johnson, NCLA, Linux+, LPIC-1, DCTS
def cat(openfile): #Emulates cat#
    with open(openfile) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return ''.join(lines)
def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
    for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
        if CONTAINING in item:
            print(item.strip()) #I implemented the give suggestion

VAR = GETLINEWITH(cat('./Base.xaiml'), 'terminal'))
```

**Results:**

I tried Jon Clements suggestion:

```
with open('./Base.xaiml') as fin:
    matching = ('terminal' in line for line in fin)
    for line in matching:
        VAR = matching
print(VAR)
```

However, the output is one memory address. ''.join() and group() do not help.

**Edit2:**

Newest code
Issues - nonetype error and the output cannot be saved to a variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Made by Devyn Collier Johnson, NCLA, Linux+, LPIC-1, DCTS
def cat(openfile): #Emulates cat#
    with open(openfile) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return ''.join(lines)
def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
    for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
        if CONTAINING in item:
            print(item.strip())
for line in GETLINEWITH(cat('./Base.xaiml'), 'terminal'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: `cat` does more than read a file.  It's about con*cat*enating lines.

Comment: The answers you linked have working solutions - why are you not just using one of those that will solve this ?

Comment: The answers in those question works if you change `print x` to `print(x)`. Your complicated "read-split-paste-split-search" logic is unnecessary.

Comment: By the way there is no point to `.readlines()` and then `''.join(lines)` immediately after.  That's the same as just `.read()`

Comment: @wim I know, but that is the name I choose since it resembles cat.

Comment: Did you see the `list=` line I posted... that'll generate a list of all the matches... All you've done is loop over the matches and assign it to `VAR` each time, so you'll end up with the last one...

Comment: @JonClements Output = [False, False, .......]

Comment: @JonClements I am wanting to save the plain text to a variable.

Comment: @JonClements Notice that I said I wanted to emulate that specific awk command.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson sorry - brain burp - changed the generator expression to return the lines, not a boolean if something is in the line

Comment: @JonClements Okay, "return" only works in functions (return not in function error). I have my newest code under "Edit2". I get some "NoneType" error and the output will not save to a variable.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson because you're printing it in the function, and not returning anything so it implicitly returns `None`.... why are you not using `yield` as I suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, note that I am just putting together everyone elses comments explicitly for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def cat(openfile):
  with open(openfile) as file:
    return file.read()

def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
  for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
    if CONTAINING in item:
      yield item.strip()

matchedlines = []

for line in GETLINEWITH(cat('./Base.xaiml'), 'terminal'):
   print(line)
   matchedlines.append(line)

print(matchedlines)
```

The `matchedlines` variable is just an example for you of one way to save the matched lines in a variable.

An alternative `GETLINEWITH` implementation is:

```
import re

def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
  for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
    m = re.search(CONTAINING, item)
    if m:
      yield m.string
```

Which will let you match on regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I like how you put it all together for me.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway - the reason it "stops" is because you're returning after a match....

```
def GETLINEWITH(FILECONTENTS, CONTAINING):
    for item in FILECONTENTS.split('\n'):
        if CONTAINING in item:
            return item.strip() # <---- returns as soon as something's found
```

Change it to a `yield` to make the function a generator and then loop over it:

```
for line in GETLINEWITH(cat('./Base.xaiml'), 'terminal'):
    print(line)
```

Ultimately, your function should just be:

```
with open('thefile') as fin:
    matching = (line for line in fin if 'something' in line)
    for line in matching:
        # do something
```

Or, put them all into a list:

```
lines = list(matching)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I save this to a variable? If I change the code to save this as a variable, the results are printed to the screen.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson made a couple of edits... does that answer your question?

Comment: Jon, I tried your idea. See my edit for the results. Close, but not quite. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks Jon for all of the help and sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

File objects are iterable, and a list comprehension can be used to filter the input.

```
with open('./Base.xaiml','r') as lines:
    matching_lines = [ line.rstrip('\n')
                       for line in lines
                       if line.find('terminal') != -1 ]

for line in matching_lines:
    print line         # change to print(line) for python 3.x
```

EDIT: or if you really want it to be a function

```
def matching_lines(filename, substring):
    """ Return all the lines in a file that contain a given substring. """
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        return [s.rstrip('\n') for s in f if s.find(substring) != -1]

for s in matching_lines('./Base.xaiml', 'terminal'):
    print s
```